# rails: produce pdf and render it as image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to produce a pdf and send it as a file, or, better, render it as an image in the browser, using imagemagick and wicked_pdf.

I'm able to send something, but it's not recognized as an image by the OS.
The pdf string is generated correctly, so I suppose the problem is in the image part

this is the code of my controller:

```
  format.jpg do
    @format = :pdf

    pdfstr =  render_to_string 'generated_graphics/tag.erb', :pdf => "tag", :layout => nil, :page_height => '38mm', :page_width => '129mm'

    file = Tempfile.new('foo')
    file.write pdfstr
    file.close

    require 'RMagick'  
    pdf = Magick::ImageList.new(file.path)
    send_data pdf.write("myimage.jpg"), :type => 'image/jpg'
  end
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why you want to send the pdf as an image rather than a pdf?

Comment: I don't want to send the pdf as an image, but to convert it to an image and send it

Comment: `Magick::Image.read(file.path)` works for me. However, I really don't understand your implication. If the final result you need is a JPEG file from your HTML template then there is no need for you to use `WickedPdf`. Simply use `IMGKit` as @iwiznia suggested. Also, you _don't_ have a PDF file you are generating it on the fly using `WickedPdf`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at imagemagick and rmagick plugin for ruby. This allows you to do all kinds of image conversions, including PDF to jpeg.

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

EDIT:

untested sample code:

```
require 'RMagick' 

pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("doc.pdf")
pdf.write("myimage.jpg")
```

if doc.pdf has 3 pages, this should output 3 images: myimage.jpg.0 myimage.jpg.1 myimage.jpg.2

take a look at the end of the documentation [on this page](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/), which shows
 a similar example with a multi-frame gif converted to multiple PNGs

Comment: +1 Could possibly use the [length](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#length) and  [montage](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#montage) option to create a single image, e.g. `pdf = Magick::ImageList.new('doc.pdf'); m = pdf.montage; m.tile = "1x#{pdf.length}"; m.write('doc.pdf.montage.jpg')`. That's also untested code.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to have an image I think you can skip the pdf stuff alltoghether, there's no sense of converting it first to pdf and then to image.
Have a look at [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit), it allows to generate an image from an html string.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to transform a pdf to an image, but you can have both, the pdf that you are already generating and the image that you generate with IMGKit